# Visual Studio 2013 - WPF properties freeze periodically

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, freeze

My properties window (WPF & C#) will "freeze" after sometime, meaning that I can not edit values, as I can not even enter the textboxes. Weirdly enough, I do can edit anything without text boxes (such as colors, gradients and check boxes).

[image]
[image]

I have marked red the elements I can not even enter, and green the elements which I can edit normally.

The XAML editor works fine, it is just the properties window. Restarting Visual Studio fixes the problem, aber after 10-30 minutes, the problem repeats.

I'm using Visual Studio Update 4 Community Edition.

Comment: Is there any code in the constructor of the window or user controls? The designer creates an instance so if the constructor is loading or attempting to load data from a database it might freeze.

Comment: If it is the same problem I have, it is the process called something like Microsoft UI XAML editor. I don't recall off the top of my head. Go to Task Manager and kill that process. It won't hurt anything, it will restart immediately, but you will be able to get back to work. This happens even if you haven't been in the xaml editor. This problem has followed my project from VS 2010 all the way through and including 2013.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd I'm using the package Mahapps.Metro. Here is the source of the window:
`<controls:MetroWindow x:Class="Test1.frmMainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
Title="Test1" Height="318" Width="808">`

Comment: @Jacobus21 - Is there any code in the constructor?

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd Do you mean the C# code which opens the window?

Comment: I have the same problem... I just avoid using the properties window.. but make sure it's not "docked" against another "normal" window, or it'll freeze that one too :-)

Comment: @Jacobus21 - yes, the constructor in C# or the Loaded event handler of the window

Comment: The windows are opened by `new frmMainWindow().Show();`. The constructor of the window would be `public frmMainWindow()
{
 InitializeComponent();
}`

Comment: I have had similar events like these in properties window as well as other windows such as the Edit window going dead.  Or even VS2013 itself requiring a reboot.  Very irritating in this day and age.  Here's what I did to get this settled down, I kept removing plug-ins until the problem went away.  I believe there was a bad release of the excellent CodeMaid tool a while back (since fixed) which seemed to be the root cause but I can't say that for sure...

Comment: @JohnPeters I don't have any plug-ins installed except ReSharper, but the problem occurred to me almost a year ago when I didn't have any add-ons at all.

Comment: Ok so the root problem in those types of cases is that when the IDE attempts to call the initialize methods of those classes, there's something that is either blocking or worse.  However, if an exception is thrown it should just show up in the designer window.  If you are sure that none of these issues are the root cause then you should reinstall VS2013.  I've had to do it three times in past 4 months.

Comment: Does this only happen in MetroWindows from MahApps? Like @ErnodeWeerd I'm wondering if that class is running some code at design-time that busts the Properties window.

Answer (score 0):

I found that selecting one of the properties that works (such as `Brush`) unfreezes all the properties and events solving the issue in a simple fashion.